# python-style class variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, class, backbone.js

It can be difficult to find these kinds of questions since they can be phrased so many different ways, so please forgive me if this is a duplicate.  I'd like to define class variables on a backbone model in such a way that they are still available on instances.  This could be done like so:

```
var
    foo_base = { foo: bar },
    FooModel = Backbone.Model.extend(foo_base, foo_base);
```

But this is quite ugly as it involves feeding the same object as both the instance and class prototype.  Is there a simpler way to do this that involves only one use of `foo_base` or `foo`?

Comment: I should add that it is definitely possible to override the behavior of `Backbone.Model.extend()` so that a third argument can be passed which is applied to both.  I just wondered if there was a nice way to do this already built in.

Answer (score -1):

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-extend

```
Backbone.Model.extend(properties, [classProperties])
```

I am unable to understand why you want to send the same object as instance properties & classProperties.

To create a model without instance properties but with classProperties, you can do something like

```
var foo_base = { foo: bar },
    FooModel = Backbone.Model.extend({}, foo_base);
```

Comment: As it states in the question, the variables need to be bound to both the instance and the class.

Comment: well, then the code in the question is the perfect way to do it.